# How do I find the type of a delimiter?

Tags: delimiter

I have a log file that has a delimiter that I haven't seen before. It isn't tab or comma delimited as I would have noticed it already. When I open the log file (a .gz compressed file), the fields are delimited and separated by this black field with the letters `SOH`.

I've tried copying that `SOH` into Google and other editors, but only see the same character again. When copied into Google, I see a square with 4 numbers: 0, 0, 0, 1.

How do I figure out what the exact character of the delimiter?

Comment: Please post some of the file's contents, and tag this question with the language the file is written in.

Answer (score 2):

`SOH` is ASCII character 0x01 or Unicode character U+0001. It is also sometimes known as `^A` (Control-A). It stands for "Start of Heading". For more information, see [C0 Control Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29).